# Load data to GdkPixbufLoader from g_input_stream_read

Tags: c, gtk

I load some data from file:

```
GInputStream* input_stream;
GFile *file = g_file_new_for_path(file_path);

input_stream = g_file_read(file,generator_cancellable ,NULL);
g_input_stream_read(input_stream, buffer, sizeof (buffer),generator_cancellable,error);
```

How can i load `g_input_stream_read` function result to the GdkPixbufLoader object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `GdkPixbufLoader` and pass the data you read from `GInputStream` to it:

```
GdkPixbufLoader *loader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new ();
gint num_bytes = g_input_stream_read (input_stream, buffer, ...);
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write (loader, buffer, num_bytes, error);
```

However, this makes sense if you perform reading asynchronously or in chunks (to e.g. show a progressively loaded JPEG or PNG).  If you just read all the data at once in a blocking manner, use simpler `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream()`.